# error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)()' to 'void (*)()' -- what?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, gcc, function-pointers

I am trying to pass a callback function from C++ to OpenGL (C API):

```
gluQuadricCallback(qobj, GLU_ERROR, errorCallback);
```

where `errorCallback` is a function in a file compiled as C++ code and is declared as

```
void errorCallback();
```

The code compiles cleanly with g++ 4.4 on Linux but gives the following error with mingw32 g++ 4.4 on Windows:

```
..\glwidget.cpp:172: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)()' to 'void (*)()'

..\glwidget.cpp:172: error:   initializing argument 3 of 'void gluQuadricCallback(GLUquadric*, GLenum, void (*)())'
```

Is it some sort of C and C++ mix problem? How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:** `void GLAPIENTRY errorCallback();` **doesn't compile either** :(
..\glwidget.cpp:129: error: expected initializer before 'errorCallback'
Now it's almost sure it is a calling convention issue and has **nothing to do with C linkage**, see the comments below Thomas' answer.

**UPDATE 2:** It seems to me I just run into a messy OpenGL issue concerning `GLAPIENTRY`, `APIENTRY` and `_GLUfuncptr`. Here is a VERY LONG discussion on portability issues:
http://lists.openscenegraph.org/pipermail/osg-users-openscenegraph.org/2007-October/003023.html

Comment: Needing extern "C" on errorCallback?  (but even if it is true, I'd report a bug to gcc if the error message you give is the full one, it is confusing).

Comment: What do you get with `extern "C" void errorCallback();` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was missing: `errorCallback` is a function in a file compiled as **C++ code** so there is no need for `extern "C"`.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: `extern "C"` only applies to name mangling when exporting functions, so it's not relevant here.

Comment: @Thomas... name mangling *and* calling conventions. The two functions may have the same signature but different calling conventions and that would make them incompatible.

Comment: @dribeas: Ah, indeed. Thanks for teaching me something!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that's all you're getting for an error, that's a pretty shitty message. This is an issue with calling conventions.

From my `glu.h`:

```
GLAPI void GLAPIENTRY gluQuadricCallback (GLUquadric* quad, GLenum which, _GLUfuncptr CallBackFunc);
```

`_GLUfuncptr` is defined as:

```
typedef void (GLAPIENTRYP _GLUfuncptr)();
```

with

```
#ifndef GLAPIENTRYP
#define GLAPIENTRYP GLAPIENTRY *
#endif

#ifndef GLAPIENTRY
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__MINGW32__)
#define GLAPIENTRY __stdcall
#else
#define GLAPIENTRY
#endif
#endif
```

That explains the difference between Linux and mingw.

From this, you'd think you need to declare your callback as

```
void GLAPIENTRY errorCallback();
```

and a `__stdcall` will be slapped onto it when appropriate.

However, as Ali notes in the comments below, slapping `GLAPIENTRY` onto the callback signature doesn't always work. It seems that the [GLU 1.3 spec](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glx/) simply specifies that a `void (*func)()` is accepted. Since some implementations require a `_GLUfuncptr` instead, which includes the `GLAPIENTRY` requirement, but others don't define `GLAPIENTRY` at all, there is a portability problem here.

A possible workaround might be:

```
#ifndef GLAPIENTRY
#define GLAPIENTRY
#endif
```

and declare all callbacks with the `GLAPIENTRY` macro nevertheless.

Comment: +1 for the "If that's all you're getting for an error, that's a pretty shitty message." :) What should I do? Shall I write to the mingw developers?

Comment: @Thomas: `void GLAPIENTRY errorCallback();` doesn't compile either: ..\glwidget.cpp:129: error: expected initializer before 'errorCallback' What's wrong?

Comment: @Thomas: No :( As I said before errorCallback is defined in a file compiled as C++ code and I do not want to change that. What works is: `__stdcall void errorCallback();` So what should I do then?

Comment: @Ali: you don't have to compile a function as C in order to give it "C" linkage.

Comment: @Thomas: `'APIENTRY void errorCallback();'` works on both platforms. Is APIENTRY the macro I should use? Or is there a better?

Comment: @Steve: Thanks, I did not know that **defining** a function in an extern "C" block is valid in a C++ source file. Apperently it is. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Steve: Anyhow, it seems to be pretty much a calling convetion issue.

Comment: @Ali: I think (but I'm not sure) that `APIENTRY` is a Windows-specific thing. It seems that `_GLUfuncptr` is a bit un(der)documented though, so you might want to check in your own header files how it's defined, and use the appropriate macros to match that definition.

Comment: @Thomas: `'void APIENTRY errorCallback();'` works on both platforms too. Is APIENTRY a macro that is wise to use (it won't change and works on other platforms)?

Comment: I would expect `APIENTRY` to be undefined entirely on non-Windows platforms. Again, open up your header files and check what they're saying, or run your program through the preprocessor and see what comes out.

Comment: @Ali. Do you include glu.h (dirrectly or indirectly) in the file where errorCallback is declared? If not than this might explain why you get an error with void GLAPIENTRY errorCallback();. It might be that GLAPIENTRY is undefined at the moment you are trying to use it...

Comment: Place #ifndef GLAPIENTRY
void () { }
#endif before the function declaration. If it gives you an error for the line containing void () {} then GLAPIENTRY is not defined

Comment: @ds27680: On Linux GLAPIENTRY is defined, on Win32 it isn't, on Win32 APIENTRY is defined. glu.h IS included on Win32. Using APIENTRY is OK on both platforms. But check out the link at UPDATE 2 at the end of my question, this APIENTRY stuff is a portability nightmare :(

Comment: @Thomas: I would like to accept your answer. Could you please remove the extern "C" stuff as the problem has nothing to do with C linkage, and add a note saying that the problem is a GLAPIENTRY, APIENTRY and _GLUfuncptr portability issue with OpenGL? Thanks.

Comment: @Ali: I've looked at the spec and updated my answer accordingly. I didn't mention `APIENTRY` because it's a Windows-specific thing, which has little to do with all this, except having a similar name.